# Generating a Key (com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key) from string

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I have a table country in mysql which have fields code(PrimaryKey), offname, actualname all are varchars.
I want to create corresponding Entity using JPA

```
@Entity
public class Country{
       @Id
       private Key code;

    private String offname;
    private String actualname;
}
```

I want to set the Key my self. I dont want it to be system generated. For this I will have to create Key and set it before I persist the object. Now the problem is how to do I create Key from the string.
Can I do something like `Key k = new Key("USA")`. I do not find such constructor. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Keyfactory.createKey](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key.html) method. You should be able to do `KeyFactory.createKey("Country", "USA");`